# Installing MSBuildTools 2017 (vs_buildtools) with Chef

Tags: windows, visual-studio, chef-infra

I was wondering if anyone has managed to figure out how to get MSBuildTools 2017 installed with Chef 11 (I'm sorry, I'm behind the times).

Installer: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017 (under Build Tools for VS2017)

I've tried two different ways, and both just seem to run the executable and then exit out.

I've tried both --quiet and --passive as command line switches and both seem to act exactly the same.

I can run this on the server, and it installs it, so I think my command line action is correct:

```
vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe --passive --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools
```

The execute resource:

```
unless ::File.directory?('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools')
  remote_file vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_installer do
    source 'http://myartifactory.localdomain.com/artifactory/chef/Installers/VisualStudioBuildTools/2017/vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe'
    action :create
  end

  execute 'Install-VS-BuildTools-2017' do
    command "#{vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_installer} --quiet --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools"
    action :run
  end
end
```

This seems to run successfully, but it ultimately doesn't install what I need.

```
execute[Install-VS-BuildTools-2017] action run[2017-08-09T11:42:05-04:00] INFO: Processing execute[Install-VS-BuildTools-2017] action run (hps-windows::build_server line 252)
[2017-08-09T11:42:06-04:00] INFO: execute[Install-VS-BuildTools-2017] ran successfully

- execute c:/windows/temp/vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe --quiet --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools

[2017-08-09T11:42:06-04:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 65.787128 seconds
```

The windows_package resource:

```
windows_package 'Always Run unless the guard says otherwise' do
  source 'http://myartifactory.localdomain.com/artifactory/chef/Installers/VisualStudioBuildTools/2017/vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe'
  options '--quiet --wait --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools'
  installer_type :custom
  action :install
  not_if { ::File.directory?('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools') } 
end
```

The output for this is:

```
[2017-08-09T12:26:48-04:00] INFO: remote_file[C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache/vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe] updated file contents C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache/vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe

- update content in file C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache/vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe from e89957 to 68a678
    (new content is binary, diff output suppressed)

[2017-08-09T12:26:48-04:00] INFO: Starting installation...this could take awhile.


[2017-08-09T12:26:49-04:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 65.276391 seconds
```

A bit of extra information, if I use the wait command, it gives a -200 error and does this:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '-200'
---- Begin output of c:/windows/temp/vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools ----
STDOUT: Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1028\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\2052\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1055\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1046\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1042\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1036\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1029\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\3082\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1040\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1031\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1045\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1041\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1049\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1033\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.RemoteControl.Net35.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.Net35.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.Net35.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.Internal.Net35.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Newtonsoft.Json.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\System.Threading.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\zh-Hans\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\cs\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\de\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\es\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\fr\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\it\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\zh-Hant\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\ja\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\ko\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\pl\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\pt-BR\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\ru\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\tr\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.config...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe.config...
Preparing: C:\Users\Administrator\f3ce1450c1e0b7515b5ec5ed\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.json...
STDERR:
---- End output of c:/windows/temp/vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools ----
```

Which leads me to believe that maybe it's running this command, unpacking everything, and then expecting another call later on using maybe the same command line window (which probably wouldn't exist in chef land) to exist and run the next command.

-------------- **Update 8/28/2017** ----------------
I switched to using this instead, and it didn't work either:
        vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_install_zip =  'c:/windows/temp/vs_buildtools_2017.zip'
        vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_install_location = 'c:/windows/temp/vs_buildtools_2017'
        vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_installer_dir ='c:/windows/temp/vs_buildtools_2017/Installer'
        vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_installer = 'c:/windows/temp/vs_buildtools_2017/Installer/vs_installershell.exe'

```
    if ::File.directory?('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools')
      file vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_install_zip do
        action :delete
      end

      directory vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_install_location do
        action :delete
      end
    else
      remote_file vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_install_zip do
        source 'http://myartifactory.localdomain.com/artifactory/chef/Installers/VisualStudioBuildTools/2017/vs_buildtools_2017.zip'
        action :create
      end

      # Unzip Windows 8.1 SDK
      windows_zipfile vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_install_location do
        source vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_install_zip
        action :unzip
        not_if { ::File.directory? vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_install_location }
      end

      execute 'Install-VS-BuildTools-2017' do
        command "#{vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_installer} --passive --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools"
        cwd vs_buildtools_2017_msbuild_installer_dir
        action :run
      end
    end
```

Output:

```
[8/25/2017, 15:59:51] === Logging started: 2017/08/25 15:59:51 ===
[8/25/2017, 15:59:51] Executable: C:\windows\temp\vs_buildtools__540411490.1488812665.exe v15.0.26430.16
[8/25/2017, 15:59:51] --- logging level: standard ---
[8/25/2017, 15:59:51] Directory 'C:\Users\Administrator\7d66710b377678a993285658a9e2\' has been selected for file extraction
[8/25/2017, 15:59:51] Extracting files to: C:\Users\Administrator\7d66710b377678a993285658a9e2\
[8/25/2017, 15:59:51] Extraction took 172 milliseconds
[8/25/2017, 15:59:51] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --passive --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools'
[8/25/2017, 15:59:52] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[8/25/2017, 15:59:52] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x0
[8/25/2017, 15:59:52] === Logging stopped: 2017/08/25 15:59:52 ===
```

-------------- **Update 9/6/2017** ----------------
I engaged Chef support, and apparently chef is installing or at the very least using installer files located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer, while the normal installer uses the Program Files (x86) analog.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I'm looking into setting up build servers using visual studio build tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it working.

```html
# Installs msbuild tools 2017
package_checksum = '{MY CHECKSUM}'
package_source = '{URL TO ARTIFACTORY REPO}/vs_buildtools__730419789.1549921800.exe'

msbuild_location = ::File.join('c:',
                               'Program Files (x86)',
                               'Microsoft Visual Studio',
                               '2017',
                               'BuildTools',
                               'MSBuild',
                               '15.0',
                               'Bin',
                               'msbuild.exe')

# Note: Msbuild tools is a pain and a half to update. I currently manually uninstall it before updating because it has a hard time figuring out what it's doing.
command = '--quiet --wait --norestart'\
' --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools'\
' --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools'
package 'msbuild tools 2017' do
  source package_source
  checksum package_checksum
  installer_type :custom
  action :install
  returns [0, 3010]
  options command
  not_if do
    ::File.exist?(msbuild_location)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Update -- check gem versions

```
gem 'winrm', '~> 2.0'
gem 'winrm-fs', '~> 1.0'
```

Recipe used for Windows Server 2012r2:

```
windows_package 'msbuild tools' do
  source 'https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe'
  installer_type :custom
  action :install
  returns [0, 3010]
  not_if {::File.exist?('c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\msbuild.exe')}
  options '--passive --norestart'
end
```

I used Chef 12 with options `'/passive /norestart'`

I changed the options to `'--passive --norestart'` and it worked.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me :(
Maybe the difference between chef 11 and 12? IDK